# Literature on noise removal in OCR applications

Tags: image-processing, reference-request

Could someone point out the core texts or articles most useful on techniques for the removal of noise from scanned text for OCR applications?

Comment: While this is out of my area of expertise, that sounds like a very broad question. What sort of noise are you trying to remove? Dust present on the paper during the scan? Noise from the image sensor? Something else? Grayscale? Color? Monochrome?

Comment: They are black and white scans of old books with discolored pages and the   pages end up  with black small random shaped spots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Google research](http://research.google.com/) has some excellent papers, see for example:

[An Overview of the Tesseract OCR Engine](http://research.google.com/pubs/pub33418.html)

Also, it seems that stackoverflow has a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180629/ocr-and-image-preprocessing-techniques

The most powerful image filtering techniques that I'm aware are graph-cuts based, 
which run in the following steps:

1. Calculate a (sparse) distance matrix between pixels (based on their intensity)
2. Spectral Clustering, keep only the lowest 3-8 eigenvectors
3. K-means clustering of the eigenvectors